# how to override functions from stdlib

Tags: gcc, overriding, strcpy, built-in

I would like to override strcpy and to supply my own implementation, in my strcpy I want to do something and call to the original strcpy.
How can I do that?

I'm working on linux, compiling with gcc, so I read about built in functions provided by gcc, I'm not sure if that's the way to do what I need, but I tried to use the flag -fno-builtin-strcpy, and in my strcpy call to __builtin_strcpy, but somehow it doesn't work as expected and cause some problemes:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    if(......)
    {
          ----do something---
    }

     return __builtin_strcpy(dest,src);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using gcc function wrappers:

1. Prefix your `strcpy` implementation with `__wrap_` (i.e. name it `__wrap_strcpy`).
2. In your function implementation, call the internal library function with `__real_` prefix (i.e. `__real_strcpy`).
3. In the link stage, add the switch `-wrap=strcpy`. This will cause each time the linker finds a strcpy call, it will call `__wrap_strcpy` instead if available.

Your program should be like this:

```c
char *__wrap_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    if(......) {
          ----do something---
    }

     return __real_strcpy(dest,src);
}
```

And you should add this to your LDFLAGS:

`LDFLAGS+="-wrap=strcpy"`

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I guess you might be able to do that by playing with linking order or excluding some standard libraries but I would not do that. If your SW has long life and multiple maintainers, there will be some maintenance problems at some point.

Why don't you create a new strcpy instead?

```
char *my_new_strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    if(......)
    {
          ----do something---
    }

    return strcpy(dest,src);

}
```

And use that where you need. Or does that not meet your requirements?

Comment: Actually what I really need is to check where in my code there is an overlapping between the src and dest that sent to strcpy.
 I want to check overlap and than call to the default strcpy, in order to locate cases of overlaping in my code.
so- "use that where you need" is every call to strcpy in our code.

Comment: Since you are working on linux with gcc it should be very easy for you to check that with valgrind (http://valgrind.org/). It is very useful tool and may reveal also other memory handling issues.